# In C++14 is it valid to use a double in the dimension of a new expression?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, new-expression

In C++14 given the following code:

```
void foo() {
  double d = 5.0;
  auto p1 = new int[d];
}
```

clang compiles this without diagnostic while gcc on the other hand produces the following diagnostic ([see it live in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8HDfZV)):

```
error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type
    7 |     auto p1 = new int[d];
      |                       ^
```

I specifically labeled this C++14 because in C++11 mode clang treats this as ill-formed and produces the following diagnostic ([see it live in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ooUuqM)):

```
error: array size expression must have integral or unscoped enumeration type, not 'double'
    auto p1 = new int[d];
              ^       ~
```

Is clang correct? If so what changed in C++14 to allow this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, a double allows for fractional quantities, so how would you allocate 0.75 of an integer, such as `int * p_array = new int [0.75];`?  Or take something like 0.33333333, which is kind of difficult to allocate.

Comment: I expect it to use the binary value of it as an integer even when it's a double so 0.75 would be 0011111111101 as an integer it's 16360

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no this would end up being a float to integral conversion and [would truncate the float](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour yea that's what I was thinking

Comment: @tomerzeitune Well, that (0.75 -> 0) is not what you wrote (0.75 -> 16360) ;)

Comment: @Bob__ it won't round towards zero it will refer to it as an int like type punning

Comment: @tomerzeitune Why `int`? Why not `unsigned` or `long`?

Comment: @tomerzeitune: I'm curious what basis you see for asserting that this would use type punning. Of what possible use would that be? Converting a floating-point value to an integer type (`5.0` to `5`) would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think the commenters are joking around

Answer (score 45):

Clang is correct, the key wording in [[expr.new]p6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.new#6) changes from the following in the C++11 draft:

> Every *constant-expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be an integral constant expression ([expr.const]) and evaluate to a strictly positive value. **The expression in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be of integral type, unscoped enumeration type, or a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or unscoped enumeration type exists** ([class.conv]). If the expression is of class type, the expression is converted by calling that conversion function, and the result of the conversion is used in place of the original expression. …

to [this in the C++14 draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.new#6):

> Every *constant-expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of type `std::size_t` and shall evaluate to a strictly positive value. **The expression in a *noptr-new-declarator* is implicitly converted to `std::size_t`**. …

In C++14 the requirement for the expression in a *noptr-new-declarator* was weakened to not require an integral, unscoped enumeration or a class with a 
single non-explicit conversion function to one of those types but just allow implicit conversions to *size_t*.

The change in wording came from the proposal [A Proposal to Tweak Certain C++ Contextual Conversions, v3](https://wg21.link/n3323).

Comment: I am dubious about the usefulness of allowing `double` to be used as the size of an array... it seems more likely to let bugs pass silently than anything else :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree, I believe it is a defect and that the intent was really to say `contextually implicitly converted`. I am filing a defect report on this hopefully today but who knows maybe I am wrong :-(

Comment: @MatthieuM. FYI I filed a defect report, processing takes a while so I don't expect to have an update anytime soon though.

Answer (score 1):

From [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) (for the ones that wonder like me), the phrasing remains practically the same (unlike from C++11 to C++14 as @ShafikYaghmour answered), as stated in this [C++17 draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.new#6):

> Every *constant-expression* in a *noptr-new-declarator* shall be a converted constant expression of type `std::size_t` and shall evaluate to a strictly positive value. **The expression in a *noptr-new-declarator* is implicitly converted to `std::size_t`**. [..]

with only this part `([expr.const])` missing from the C++17 draft.